# Use variable outside the success function from an ajax/jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code

```
var test;

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../views/person/controller.php?actor=person&action=checkAge",
    data: "age=" + value,
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        test = msg; 
    },
});

Validate.fail(test);
```

Now the test var should give true of false like the console does say.
But test var gives me undefined why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Probably because Validate.fail(test) occurs immediately after the asynchronous call.  Remember it is ASYNCHRONOUS, meaning it executes parallel to javascript running on your page.

Comment: Tnx this helped me out i found the solution
By doing async: false, to the call property

Comment: I am glad you figured this out but I recommend you rethink your solution.  I can't say that I understand the aspect of your application but a synchronous ajax call mostly defeats the purpose of Ajax.  Cheers.

Comment: Tnx for you tip again. But for this purpose it is really necessary. Ill try avoid this solution in the future :)

Answer (score 27):

```
 var test; // <-- (1) This code runs first  
 $.ajax({  // <-- (2) Then this runs  
    type: "GET",
    url: "../views/person/controller.php?actor=person&action=checkAge",
    data: "age=" + value,
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg); //<-- (4) Finally this is run. IF your request is a success 
        test = msg; 
    },
 });
 Validate.fail(test); // <-- (3) This runs third
```

Look at the order in which the code runs. Your variable is simply not available at that point because it's running when the code is triggered via the callback

Comment: Whats the solution, if not using `async`? (+1 for the explanation you presented)

Comment: Generally you'd show a loading indicator to the user and wait till the server response is received.

Comment: - thanks, i meant whats the solution to pass the variable/value outside of the ajax call, w/o using async

Comment: You can't do that. If you're using async and you're waiting on the result then the last part of the call is going to be within the aync block.

Comment: Thats the thing - i understand one should not use async

Comment: That's incorrect. Using async is not good/bad. It's a valid choice depending on the usecase. For example, if you were doing a server side call to validate a piece of data, then you should use async and not block the webpage till your result is received.

Answer (score 11):

```
var test;
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "../views/person/controller.php?actor=person&action=checkAge",
    data: "age=" + value,
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        test = msg; 
    },
});
Validate.fail(test);
```

//Make your ajax function synchronous, set the json parameter  "async: false", so javascript has to wait until test  is assigned a value.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var xm;

  $("#txt").ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('#txt').html(xm);
  });

  $("button").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: 'DBresult_load.php',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: { },                 //you can pass values here
      success: function(result) {xm =result;}
    });
  });


});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="txt"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button>Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the solution for passing values to variable from Ajax request. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you remove "var" before the term "test" when you declare it?

I'm not sure how the call back function is treated with jQuery , as it is wrapped within a few other extended methods.. But the reason i say leave var out in the declaration of the `test` variable is that `var` assigns test to be relative to the scope. If your callback is being treated in a certain way, you may lose the scope where `test` is defined. You may want to drop the `var` assignment and leave it as a global variable. Perhaps this will make it visible?

EDIT:: Didn't realize you were referencing the term within a function call after the async request -- i would suggest including the last statement within your callback.

:)

Comment: var describes the variable to be relative to the scope.. if you leave it out then it becomes a global variable.. research before you speak ;)

Comment: bad programming practice.. hah.

Comment: How is it irrelevant? He said that `test` is undefined... this would mean it's out of scope.. and `var` delegates the variable to the current stack... so if you drop the `var` and make it global on the heap instead, it should then be defined... do you understand variable visibility? ;)

Comment: Your argument skills are *awesome* by the way.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. You're correct in saying that if you leave out `var` it will make it a global, but how does that have any bearing on this question? The problem here is that test isn't instantiated at the point the `Validate` call is made, this is because it is given a value only when the call back is successful. If you actually instantiate when you declare it, the code will work fine (but the validate will be rendered useless since you're explicitly declaring it)

Comment: I didn't realize he was referencing the variable by another function after an async request... i thought it was just not visible within the async function