# Get variable outside function jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use variable outside the success function from an ajax/jquery call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935968/use-variable-outside-the-success-function-from-an-ajax-jquery-call)

I am trying to get a variable outside a JSON query with no success:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/diasporaduo/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc",function(json){

    videoid = json.data.items[0].id;
    });

    alert(videoid)
});
```

Comment: Anybody keeping count? We get a couple o' million of these questions *daily!*

Comment: have you tried searching?  ...  As @JosephSilber mentions this gets asked daily here . The first `A` in AJAX is for asynchronous

Comment: Sorry. I have searched but no luck yet. Maybe I will reformulate my whole code. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use the async flag:

> async (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e.
>   this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set
>   this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp"
>   requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous
>   requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while
>   the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of  async: false 
>   with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the
>   success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding
>   methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated
>   jqXHR.success().

Your code example then is:

```
var videoid;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/diasporaduo/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function (json) {
            videoid = json.data.items[0].id;
        }
    });
    alert(videoid);
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/5hE7n/

Comment: Let me counter that: you *shouldn't* use the `async` flag. Making a synchronous request should be used as a last resort, when all else fails.

Comment: Thanks, but still getting this: TypeError: json.data is undefined

Comment: have you looked into the fiddler sample, I posted

Comment: @JosephSilber: I know, but maybe it is fine for his requirement (even if asyn=false probably is never good)....