# Why cant i access ajax pulled content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use variable outside the success function from an ajax/jquery call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935968/use-variable-outside-the-success-function-from-an-ajax-jquery-call)

I have this code and i don't understand why the accessing of the html elements is only working inside the ajax success function. the form is pulled in from ajax either way but i can only access it when i put all the selects for elements of it inside the ajax function.

The `console.log('submit clicked');` gets **not** triggered this way, but inside the "ajax success" it does, i thaught everything pulled in with ajax is part of the DOM?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

console.log('ready');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'admin-ajax.php',
    data: { action: 'get_arve_form' },
    success: function(response){
        // var table = $(response).find('table');
        $(response).appendTo('body').hide();
        console.log('response');

                    [ if i move the code below this ajax function in here its workign fine why not outside of it?]

    }
});

// handles the click event of the submit button
$('#mygallery-submit').click(function(){
    console.log('submit clicked');
                [...]
        });
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your code that "doesn't work" and explains what specifically does not work.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals i did exacly that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous so your elements don't exist until the ajax call finishes.

That being said, there are two ways to fix it:

1) Move your code into the success handler

2) Use event delegation to bind your event handler to all current *and future* elements.

An example of #2:

```
$(document).on('click', '#mygallery-submit', function(){
    console.log('submit clicked');
});
```

Check out [jQFundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events) to learn more about event delegation.

Comment: so this is supposed to be that way, ok i learned something. i guess i move it inside the success then for now

Answer (score 1):

That's how ajax works.
When the external page is loaded, you have it available *only* on the success handler.
If you want it to be available elsewhere, you have to save it somehow, like you are doing.

But, the .click function gets executed before the ajax call returns successful. When you select $('#mygallery-submit'), it most likely is empty (you probably load this via ajax). So what you have to do if you want to declare the click function on document ready, rather than when the ajax page gets loaded, is to use the .on function:

```
$('body').on('click', '#mygallery-submit', function() {
    console.log('submit clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `.click()` is not a delegated handler. If the element you're trying to bind the event to doesn't exist at the time of execution, the event won't get bound. Try `.on()` instead.

```
$('body').on('click', '#mygallery-submit', function() {
    // etc.
});
```