# Javascript append to variable data echoed back from php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, echo

I have this lines of code placed inside an app i am currently developing. I send to the url the valdat variable which is then processed through a php file and then echoed back to the app. How can i append to a variable x the data the alert message displays?

```
var valdat="foo";

$.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.link./file.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
     valdat:valdat

   },

   error: function(data) {
   alert(data);

   },

   success: function(data) {
   alert(data);
},

});
```

Comment: Please describe both `data` and `x` and your desired result if you need more help

Comment: If your data in response is json then we need to parse it like `code` value = parseJSON(data) and then get required data like value.name and append it like steve told. x + = value.name

Comment: in the php file, after i process the valdat i get 12 timeslots which are integers ($slot1=1, $slot2=0, $slot3=4...etc). After that i join them with $slotsum=$slot1.$slot2.$slot3....$slot12; and i use "echo $slotsum"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean append the returning value directly to a known variable you can just use `+=`:

```
var valdat  ="foo";
var x       = "Something";

$.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.link./file.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
     valdat:valdat

   },

   error: function(data) {
        x += data; 

        alert(x); //Will output "Something" + the content of `data`

   },

   success: function(data) {
        x += data; 

        alert(x); //Will output "Something" + the content of `data`
    },

});
```

Comment: if i do that, the alert will display the value of x, which is what i wanted, but then if i want to append that x to another variable h that is going to be the text for a textbox, i get nothing.. the value of x is not transferred to h. shouldn't var h=x; do the trick?

Comment: Yeah thats correct if you want assign the value of `x` to `h` you can use `var h = x`

Answer (score 0):

this resolved it...the ajax call was being performed async which means it runs parallel with the rest of JS, meaning that the compiler does the following things:
        1)valdat=foo
        2)x=bar
        3)h=x
        4)ajax call
so the program didn't know who x was because it didn't have one until the end of it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5936026/5467736